# Attach js to the module using libraries with inline property

Tags: forms, 8

I have a module in which I have created a libraries.yml file and have attached it to the module:

```
$var[$delta] = array(
  '#theme' => 'example_theme',
  '#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      "example_theme/example-styling",
    ),
  ),
  '#file' => $output,
);
```

I want to provide a variable to the js defined in libraries.yml

How can I achieve this?

```
drupal_add_js('example = "' . $example . '";', 'inline')
```

Answer (score 2):

[drupal_add_js()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605) has been deprecated, and you cannot use it anymore.

Pass the inline variables with the `#attached` property as :

```
$var[$delta]['#attached']['drupalSettings']['yourmodule']['example'] = $example;
```

And then access the `example` variable in the JS file as

```
drupalSettings.yourmodule.example
```

*Note:* I have not tried this code, but I think it should work.

Comment: i tried this before.....din work

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `#attached` in Drupal 8. Try the following code:

```
return array(
  '#theme' => 'your_module_theme_id',
  '#someVariable' => $some_variable,
  '#attached' => array(
    'drupalSettings' => array(
      'your_module_settings' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => 'bee',
      )
    ),
    'library' =>  array(
      'your_module/library_name'
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here, `your_module/library_name` will be able to access this `drupalSettings` JavaScript via `drupalSettings.your_module_settings` and more granular `drupalSettings.your_module_settings.foo` etc.

For further reading you can look at the below links
https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515
https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843

I've used this in one of my module. This module [Visualization API](https://www.drupal.org/project/visualization) has the same as well. Might be good as example.